# Replace Post-Title with variable

Tags: php, post-type

I want to set a custom post-title with a custom-field meta in my Wordpress Theme.

The user will add a new post to the post-type. When they do they will only see the "Title", "URL", and "Publish" metas. I want to eliminate the "Title" and only show the "URL" and "Publish" meta. 
When the user pastes the URL I have a variable set to grab the custom title from the URL.

**Question:** Am I able to use this variable to generate the post-title? Something like:

```
$postid = get_the_ID();

add_post_meta( $postid, 'youtubetitle', $videotitle );

add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_replace_post_title', 100, 2);

function my_replace_post_title( $title, $id ){

 if (is_feed())
       return $title; // You don't modify the title if it is a feed

   // To change the title to the value of your metafield, first get the value of the metafield 
   $new_youtube_title = get_post_meta( $id, 'youtubetitle', $single );

   // $new_youtube_title becomes the new title
   return $new_youtube_title; 
}
```

The code above displays (no title) on all my videos when this is used, instead of pulling the $videotitle variable.

Answer (score 1):

For hiding Title in admin panel the easiest way is using CSS. Another better way is using front-end submitting plugins.

Follwoing code help you to change post title.

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'replacePostTitle', 100, 2);

function replacePostTitle($title, $id){
   if (is_feed())
       $return $title;

   //do some magic here

   return $new_title;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Looks like it can work but lets see if it does what I need it to. This is for a youtube theme. When the user inputs "Youtube URL" it outputs the title of the video into a variable. I dont want the user to have to type in the title of the video he is posting, since the Youtube URL input already does that for him on the front-end of the site. I want them to be able to paste the URL, hit Publish, and it automatically titles that post with the title from the video. Im trying to make it simpler and faster for the user to post his videos :)

Comment: example of front-end can be seen here where I am calling the youtube video title, not the post title: [theme](http://www.elevancement.com/themes/videos/hot-sauce/). `Impossible Let's Play: HOT SAUCE CHALLENGE` is the title of the youtube video, not the post title. I hope this clears things up. Is this possible?

Comment: As Pat's said, you need to save it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you can already get the YouTube title into a variable then something like the following should do it. Let's say...

```
$youtubetitle = 'A Hot Sauce Example Title';
```

You write this into the post meta like this (I think you've already done this so I'll be brief):

```
add_post_meta( 1234, 'youtubetitle', $youtubetitle );
```

'1234' is the id of the post.

You could then use the `the_title` hook to modify it:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_replace_post_title', 100, 2);

function my_replace_post_title( $title, $id ){

 if (is_feed())
       $return $title; // You don't modify the title if it is a feed

   // To change the title to the value of your metafield, first get the value of the metafield 
   $new_youtube_title = get_post_meta( $id, 'youtubetitle', $single );

   // $new_youtube_title becomes the new title
   return $new_youtube_title; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry I have not commented, I was enjoying the weekend. 

When I place this code you provided I face several issues. Since I am adding a new page the id `1234` is static, and needs to be dynamic, since i am adding the new title to the post after I publish it. Secondly when I place this code I keep getting (no title), and nothing I can do fixes it. Any ideas?

Comment: See my updated post for ideas

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to create the post first then use the value of the variable $youtubetitle to update the post content using [wp_update_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) ?

Comment: I could, with the exception that when they hit "publish" id like it toauto-update the post with the title... I want the user to paste the Youtube URL, select category, hit publish and not worry about the `title`. Maybe what I am looking to do is outside of the Wordpress function.

Comment: Im literally trying to make it so the Youtuber buying my theme doesn't have to worry about titles for posts in the custom post type. They hit "add new", paste url, and they are done. Simple, quick, and fast. But I get the feeling this isnt possible in terms of how I am thinking it. Im still very new to wordpress.

Answer (score -1):

```
$string="jomon is name my";
for($i=strlen($string);$i>=0;$i--)
{
    $char.=$string{$i};

}
echo $char."<br/>";

for($i=0; $i<strlen($char);$i++)
 {
  if($char[$i+1]==" " || $char[$i+1]=="")
  {
   for($temp=$i; $temp>=0 && $char[$temp]!=' '; $temp--)
       echo $char[$temp];
  }
  echo " ";
 }

?>
```